# how to stop login button app asking for friends list permission

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-login

I have implemented the facebook login button but im getting complaints from people saying the app is requesting access to friends list and because of this they dont trust it because they think the app will have the ability to send messages to their friends. I know that this isnt what the app does but the average user doesnt.

I have no use for the friends list. All i use is the email address along with the user id and username. This friends list access is there by default i didnt add the permission so i want to remove it because it took quite a bit of work for me to set all this up and its annoying to hear complaints about a permission request that i dont even require.

This is the code im using to get the info for the user from facebook.

```
require_once("facebook.php");
    $config = array();
    $config['appId'] = 'xxx';
    $config['secret'] = 'xxx';
    $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $loginURL = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email'));
    try
    {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $details = $facebook->api($uid);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $uid =0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The basic permissions text is **"APPLICATION would like to access your public profile and friend list."** This is the default text to auth any app, even without any permissions added.

Comment: why is this can it not be overridden? When creating the app the documentation was saying the less permissions the better which i understand but then after saying that they go and request permissions i dont even want and dont seem to let me remove

Comment: Hey @DanHastings have you found anyway around this. I went to pain staking effort to design a permission free app, only to wind up stuck with this dialog.

Comment: No sadly not. ive gotten several complaints about this permission since its extremely frustrating. Its a requirement by facebook and there is no way around it. I never really round a concrete answer as to why they even ask for the permission but sadly no way i could find to get around it

Comment: You said 
"Its a requirement by facebook and there is no way around it."
have they officially said it any where ?

Comment: Facebook did announce about the basic permission change. It seems that public profile and friend list is a must-included permission now. I'm sad too. http://www.insidefacebook.com/2012/12/12/how-changes-to-facebooks-app-auth-process-affect-developers/

Answer (score 0):

Asking for basic info + friends list is the most basic permissions that an app can request. If you do not supply any additional read permissions, then those two permissions are the only ones that will show up, and I do not believe you can remove them.

I believe we do this because when integrating your app with Facebook, the inherent reason is to make your app social and to provide a distribution channel for your app. So the friends list permission is added by default because you should use that permission to encourage the user to share your app with their friends if they wish to do so with the app requests dialog etc.

So you can remove form your app from social

also check this link for more info : [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457779/facebook-login-permission-issue/27265530#27265530)