# Facebook Login permission issue

Tags: facebook, permissions, privacy

As you can see from the screenshot(1) below, I am getting an additional option asking - 'Edit the info you provide'. I'm getting only getting public profile and email Id permissions from the user. What should I do to avoid getting this option?

[image]

I have not see such an option (screenshot 2) in other websites. Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: That is a new feature in API v2.0. There is nothing you can do to remove that option.

Answer (score 1):

Until April 2015 you can still use the v1.0 version of the Facebook API after that you got permission from facebook app. 
You can check this link for this which published from the facebook [Click Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login/#pre-f8-apps).

Also you need to approve this app from facebook

```
1) Go in your App. (i.e. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/*************/dashboard/)
2) After Click On Status & Review 
3) Click on Second Tab ( Items In review ) and Select Start a new Submission
```

Over Here you can select a permission and send to facebook for application approval.

after the approval you can get all detail from the user.

Click Here For More Detail For Facebook Docs : [Click Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review)

Answer (score 0):

Until April 2015 you can still use the v1.0 version of the Facebook API which will give you the second view.

For example on Android you can modify the variable GRAPH_API_VERSION in ServerProtocol.java in the Facebook SDK to achieve this. I would however strongly recommend that you don't do that :)